# Prevent redirections when using Omniauth Registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, omniauth

I am using Omniauth to authenticate my JSON API.

After submitting to /auth/identity/register, I want to return the results without redirecting the user. How can this be done?

In order to allow OmniAuth::Strategies::Identity.registration_phase to accept JSON data, I have monkey patched it by replacing the first line with this:

```
    if !env["rack.input"].nil?
      attributes = JSON.parse(request.env["rack.input"].read)
    else
      attributes = (options[:fields] + [:password, :password_confirmation]).inject({}){|h,k| h[k] = request[k.to_s]; h}
    end
```

This works fine and in the case of failure, I am setting on_failed_registration to handle that - but in the case of success, I just want to return a 200 with the result rather than a redirect.

I have tried to monkeypatch OmniAuth::Strategies::Identity.callback_phase as follows with no luck (it still redirects even though it is printing my puts):

```
  def callback_phase
    binding.pry
    return fail!(:invalid_credentials) unless identity
    if !env["action_dispatch.request.content_type"].to_s.match(/json/).nil?
      puts 'Not redirecting because this is JSON.'
      return
    else
      super
    end
  end
```

Comment: just hit on the same issue, any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

shioyama - I hope this helps you, this is what I am doing.

```
module OmniAuth
  module Strategies
    # The identity strategy allows you to provide simple internal
    # user authentication using the same process flow that you
    # use for external OmniAuth providers.
    class Identity

      def registration_phase
        if env['CONTENT_TYPE'].match(/x-www-form/).nil?
          attributes = JSON.parse(request.env["rack.input"].read)
        else
          attributes = (options[:fields] + [:password, :password_confirmation]).inject({}){|h,k| h[k] = request[k.to_s]; h}
        end
        @identity = model.create(attributes)
        if @identity.persisted?
          env['PATH_INFO'] = callback_path
          callback_phase
        else
          if options[:on_failed_registration]
            self.env['omniauth.identity'] = @identity
            options[:on_failed_registration].call(self.env)
          else
            registration_form
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```